# cURL to angularJS

Tags: angularjs, curl

i have this curl link

```
curl https://api.cardinity.com/v1/<endpoint> \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="<your_consumer_key>", \
      oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", \
      oauth_timestamp="<timestamp>", \
      oauth_nonce="<unique_random_string>", \
      oauth_version="1.0", \
      oauth_signature="<computed_oauth_signature>"'
```

I just dont know what to do with authorization, where to put OAuth,

i am doing like this

```
 headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: {
                    'oauth_consumer_key': 'xxxxxxxxx'
```

any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this,

```
headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key=xxxxxxxx'
```

you might need to remove quotes, not sure.